# How to recover the breeze style on kde plasma?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, breeze, kde-plasma

I'm developing an application with PyQT5 and I really like the default style which is breeze. I would like to know how I can take it and put it in dependency so that it works the same under a windows. Thanks for your feedback.

I tried to clone the repository: https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets except that this did not work well I can not generate a qcss file easy to put in dependency.

Comment: That project clearly says that it can compile a resource file that you can then use within the program just by importing it. Did you do that?